# disable the working of save button

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have done a VF page in this pages controller. I have written a query to get some record. If the condition is false then an error message is shown. If the error message is shown then I want to disable the working of the save button.

Is it possible to enable the working of save button, or disable a save button? In Apex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute of an [`<apex:commandbutton>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_compref_commandButton.htm) can be set to enable/disable a button. Setting this attribute to a bound Apex variable would allow you to control whether or not the button is enabled in your Apex [Controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_custom.htm) or [Extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm).

**Example Visualforce markup:**

```
<apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" disabled="{!myApexBooleanVariable}" />
```

**Example Controller or Extension Apex code:**

```
public Boolean myApexBooleanVariable {get;set;}
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `disabled="{!myApexBooleanVariable}"` instead of `rendered`. If `rendered` is assigned with `{!myApexBooleanVariable}`, then the control will either be displayed or not be displayed, depending on the value.